# Where can I get a rotation specific appFrame?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, orientation

How can I retrieve a rotation specific applicationFrame/screen bounds? The "applicationFrame" method always returns 768x1024 on the iPad, no matter whether the device is in landscape or portrait mode. I am looking for a method that would return me 1024x768 if the device is in landscape and 768x1024 if its in portrait.

I am sure there is something like this out there but I just can't find it. In case it really doesn't exist, how do make your iPad apps landscape and portrait compatible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out applicationFrame works fine, but only if the autorotation is properly implemented! In my case the controller of the view that was added as subview to the UIWindow was released too early, which seems to cause applicationFrame to break along with the autorotation mechanism. I think this is because the responder chain can no longer function properly, yet I did not verify this.

Answer (score 0):

```
[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation
```

Will return one of

```
typedef enum {
    UIDeviceOrientationUnknown,
    UIDeviceOrientationPortrait,
    UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,
    UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft,
    UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight,
    UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp,
    UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown
} UIDeviceOrientation;
```

From there, you can deduce what the current frame should be.

Comment: I know this one, but FaceUp and FaceDown are not very helpful. The same is available for the status bar (interface orientation), however, I wanted to avoid this extra step, it just seems weird that there isn't a "convenience" method for such a common issue

Comment: Try checking the window frame then, instead of the app frame.

Comment: The window bounds and frame are also unadjusted, they always return 768x1024. Good idea though.

Comment: Use UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape() or UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait() then.  Those should always work.

Comment: Feeling very stupid right now, had an (at first sight) unrelated issue with the UIViewController stack I built for the app (my UINavigationController who's view was added as window subview was released too early), after fixing this applicationFrame works like a charm now... Thanks for your answer though!